# How to lock Windows 7 computer automatically instead of sleeping?

Tags: windows-7, windows, lock

After a set time period I'd like to have my computer lock. I do not want the computer to go into any kind of power saving mode, I'd just like it to lock the screen.

Which setting must I configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a blank screensaver?

[Windows 7](https://faqs.aber.ac.uk/156)

1. From the desktop, right-mouse click and click on Personalize
2. Choose Screen Saver from the window which appears
3. Tick the On resume display logon screen box and choose a Wait time
   from the menu provided e.g. 10 minutes
4. Click on Apply and then on OK to finish

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have a password configured for your account.

1. Open Screen Saver Settings by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type screen saver, and then click Set screen saver password.
2. Select the On resume, display logon screen check box, set a time when you want the screen saver to start, and then click OK. (Choose a time that's not long enough for an unauthorized person to use your computer, but not so short that if you stop working at your computer for a moment, the screen saver locks it.)

Source:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-password-for-screensaver-password#1TC=windows-7